# How to get a same size of bitmap of given image with black background

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I am developing an android application.In this application i have a image which i am showing in image view.Now i want to get the same size of bitmap of that image but replacing this image with black back ground.Please help me with it.

Comment: "replace with black background" - you can just give the ImageView a black background... or else you need to give more information about the format and requirements of your project

Comment: @Jim. Thank you .I want to replace the image color with black color and get a new bitmap which only shows black image.Actually i need to draw 2 lines on original image and then get a bitmap which shows these lines as white and other pixels of image as a black.